# How to fix: "49: CreateDataFile failed"

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am trying to write a simple audio recorder in swift, following tutorials, but for some reason the recorder fails when running .record() and throws the following error

I have tried different settings for the file recording and changing the file location, no luck.

```
    let audioFilename = getFileURL(tag: tag)

    let settings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ] as [String : Any]

    do {

        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record()}
```

Also the getFileURL methods:

```
func getFileURL(tag: Int) -> URL {

    let path = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(HelperFunctions.getRecordingName(tag: tag)).m4a")

    return path as URL

}
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
```

I get the "49:  CreateDataFile failed" error where should be none

Comment: You are getting the application folder, not the document folder so you probably get an access related error. change the enum type to `.documentDirectory ` in `getDocumentsDirectory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "applicationDirectory" created the problem. Changing it to "documentDirectory" solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying to use the current date and time in the filename. It %-encoded the space between date and time but I imagine the `/` in the date wasn't sensible in a file path!